# multi threaded program - core dumped

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, primes, realloc

I'm trying to make a multi-threaded prime numbers counter program. I've added the critical codes for the understanding (the parseargs function works great in another program and feels unnecessary and I don't want to overload you with code).

Long story short, the program compile and work well with small numbers (up to 1000 max val and 8 threads), but when I'm trying to go with bigger numbers I keep getting a lot of errors like:

segmentation fault: core dumped, Floating point exception, realloc(): invalid next size.

What's wrong with the code? I know that I should use fewer global variables but I'm trying to make it work and then I will make cleaner and better.
And the only place that I'm using realloc is inside of isprime; that works great in my other programs. What's the problem there?

```
        #include <ctype.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <math.h>
        #include <unistd.h>
        #include <pthread.h>
        #include <sys/mman.h>
        
        void parseargs(char *argv[], int argc, int *lval, int *uval, int *nval, int *tval);
        int isprime(int n);
        void setFlags();
        
        pthread_mutex_t num_lock;
        pthread_mutex_t count_lock;
        
        char *flagarr = NULL;
        int num;
        int lval = 1;//min value
        int uval = 100;//max value
        int count = 0;//primes counter
        
        int main (int argc, char **argv)
        {
          int nval = 10;// how much numbers to print
          int tval = 4;// threads number
          num = lval;
          
            if (pthread_mutex_init(&num_lock, NULL) != 0) {
                printf("\n mutex init has failed\n");
                return 1;
            } 
               if (pthread_mutex_init(&count_lock, NULL) != 0) {
                printf("\n mutex init has failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
        
          // Parse arguments
          parseargs(argv, argc, &lval, &uval, &nval, &tval);// works 100% (change the defult starting vals)
          if (uval < lval)
          {
            fprintf(stderr, "Upper bound should not be smaller then lower bound\n");
            exit(1);
          }    
          if (lval < 2)
          {
            lval = 2;
            uval = (uval > 1) ? uval : 1;
          }
          if (tval<1)
            tval=4;
        
          // Allocate flags
          flagarr= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (uval-lval+1));
          if (flagarr == NULL)
            exit(1);
            
             //Allocate threads
          pthread_t* t = (pthread_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*tval);
             if (t == NULL)
              exit(1);
              
         //start threads
          for(int i =0; i<tval ; i++){
             printf("%d\n",i);
             pthread_create(&t[i],NULL,(void*)setFlags,NULL);
             }
             
         for(int i =0; i<tval ; i++)
             pthread_join(t[i],NULL);
        
        
        
          // Print results
          nval=count;
          printf("Found %d primes from %d to %d%c", count, lval,uval , count ? ' ' : '.');
          if(count && nval>0)
            printf("and printing the first %d of them:\n",nval);
          else
            printf("\n");
          for (num = lval; (num <= uval) && (nval) ; num++)
            if (flagarr[num - lval])
            {
              nval--;
              count--;
              printf("%d%c", num, (count && nval) ? ',' : '\n');  
            }
            free(flagarr);
            free(t);
              return 0;
        }
        
        void setFlags()
        {
         int myNum;
          for (; num <= uval;)
          { 
                pthread_mutex_lock(&num_lock);
                myNum=num;
                num++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&num_lock);
                
            if (isprime(myNum))
            {
              flagarr[myNum - lval] = 1; 
              pthread_mutex_lock(&count_lock);
              count ++;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_lock);
            } else {
              flagarr[myNum - lval] = 0; 
            }
          }
        }
int isprime(int n)
{
  static int *primes = NULL;    // NOTE: static !
  static int size = 0;      // NOTE: static !
  static int maxprime;      // NOTE: static !
  int root;
  int i;

  // Init primes array (executed on first call)
   pthread_mutex_lock(&first_lock);
  if (primes == NULL)
  {
    primes = (int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    if (primes == NULL)
      exit(1);
    size = 2;
    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;
    maxprime = 3;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&first_lock);

  root = (int)(sqrt(n));

  // Update primes array, if needed
  while (root > maxprime)
    for (i = maxprime + 2 ;  ; i+=2)
      if (isprime(i))
      {
         pthread_mutex_lock(&primeFunc_lock);
        size++;
        primes = (int *)realloc(primes, size * sizeof(int));
        if (primes == NULL)
          exit(1);
        primes[size-1] = i;
        maxprime = i;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&primeFunc_lock);
        break;
      }

  // Check 'special' cases
  if (n <= 0)
    return -1;
  if (n == 1)
    return 0;

  // Check prime
  for (i = 0 ; ((i < size) && (root >= primes[i])) ; i++)
    if ((n % primes[i]) == 0)
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your function scoped `static` variables are (or 'appear to be') accessed concurrently from multiple threads without any locking/synchronization.  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: your thread function has the wrong signature. It should be `void* setFlags(void* arg);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I should use fewer global variables but I'm trying to make it work and then I will make cleaner and better.

For multithreaded programs this approach doesn't work -- you can't write a buggy program first, and make it pretty and bug-free later -- you *have to* get it bug-free first.

Also, global and static variables and threads generally don't mix.

Now, as others have noted, you access static variables in `isprime()` without any locks. Think about what would happen when thread T1 executes this code:

```
  for (i = 0 ; ((i < size) && (root >= primes[i])) ; i++)
    if ((n % primes[i]) == 0)
```

and another thread T2 executes this statement *at the same time*:

```
        primes = (int *)realloc(primes, size * sizeof(int));
```

Since `primes` is not an atomic variable, the compiler will (likely) load the value of `primes` into some register, and continue using that value through the entire loop in T1. The loop will be totally oblivious to the fact that `primes` may have already been `free()`d and `realloc()`ed in T2, and now points to entirely different memory block. T1 will continue reading the old (now dangling) memory.

Similar problems exist throughout your `isprimes()` function, and easily explain your observed crashes.

If you are on a Linux system, [Thread sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) (and [Address sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)) are your friends.

Comment: I will remember that for the my next multithreaded program.

I've added two locks to my func but I fill like the first one can be used better, what do you think ?
post edited!

Comment: @יונתןאליהו Your update didn't fix the problem (it demonstrates that you misunderstand how locks are supposed to be used). You _must_ protect any data shared between threads (`size`, `maxprime` and `primes` here), while reading _and_ writing, with the _same_ mutex. You really should try Thread sanitizer.